# Extracellular potential via a point source

Tags: potential, maxwell-equations, calculus

You can stimulate neurons extracellularly - that is, you place an electrode at a certain distance.

Assuming a punctiform electrode and a homogeneous medium, the extracellular potential (in mV) reduces to

$$V = \frac{\rho_{ext} \cdot I}{4 \cdot \pi \cdot r}$$

where I is the applied current ($\mu A$), $\rho$ (given in $k \Omega cm$) is the resisitivity of the extracellular medium and $r$ is the Euclidean distance to the cell.

Unfortunately, it is not given why this external potential simplifies like this....
How do I arrive at this? Is this a simplification from Maxwell theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula can be derived. You do not use Maxwell theory, but use Ohm's law and the assumptions that the medium is uniform and the other electrode is far far away.

You insert current $I$  from this electrode. Current $I$ will travel through the medium and reach the other electrode. Since the other electrode is far far away, we assume the current is sphere symmetrical, like radiation. Thus the density of $I$ is proportional to $1/r^2$, thus the drop of $\Delta V$ is porportional to $1/r^2$ (by Ohms law). You integrate $\Delta V$ from $r$ to $\infty$ to obtain potential at $r$, assuming potential at $\infty$ is $0$. You reach $1/r$ law by integrating $1/r^2$.

(I have studied neurons for 3 years to feel familiar with your question...)

Comment: first of all: thank you for your answer :) what do you mean by far, far away? the distances are usually in the range of 1-2mm. I still dont see the formular of $V$...

Comment: @Voeslauer123 Far far away is in comparison to $r$. That formula is just an approximation, anyway. $$V=\int_r^\infty dV=\int_r^\infty I dR = \int_r^\infty I (\rho dr / 4\pi r^2) = -\rho I/(4\pi) (1/r)|_r^\infty=\rho I/(4\pi r)$$

Comment: ahh thank you! everything is clear now :)

Comment: can one obtain this result also by using maxwell equations (Gauss's Law)?

Comment: @Voeslauer123 You can derive a "Gauss's Law for point current source in uniform resistant media" and use it. But you can't with the Gauss's Law in Maxwell equations.